# How to get the SliverPersistentHeader to "overgrow"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I'm using a `SliverPersistentHeader` in my `CustomScrollView` to have a persistent header that shrinks and grows when the user scrolls, but when it reaches its maximum size it feels a bit stiff since it doesn't "overgrow".

Here is a video of the behaviour I want (from the Spotify app) and the behaviour I have:

[image: Video of behaviour].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While looking for a solution for this problem, I came across three different ways to solve it:

1. Create a `Stack` that contains the `CustomScrollView` and a header widget (overlaid on top of the scroll view), provide a `ScrollController` to the `CustomScrollView` and pass the controller to the header widget to adjust its size
2. Use a `ScrollController`, pass it to the `CustomScrollView` and use the value of the controller to adjust the `maxExtent` of the `SliverPersistentHeader` (this is what [Eugene recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56007641/170851)).
3. Write my own Sliver to do exactly what I want.

I ran into problems with solution 1 & 2:

1. This solution seemed a bit "hackish" to me. I also had the problem, that "dragging" the header didn't scroll anymore, since the header was not *inside* the `CustomScrollView` anymore.
2. Adjusting the size of the sliver during scrolling results in strange side effects. Notably, the distance between the header and slivers below increases during the scroll.

That's why I opted for solution 3. I'm sure the way I implemented it, is not the best, but it works exactly as I want:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

/// The delegate that is provided to [ElSliverPersistentHeader].
abstract class ElSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  double get maxExtent;
  double get minExtent;

  /// This acts exactly like `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate.build()` but with
  /// the difference that `shrinkOffset` might be negative, in which case,
  /// this widget exceeds `maxExtent`.
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset);
}

/// Pretty much the same as `SliverPersistentHeader` but when the user
/// continues to drag down, the header grows in size, exceeding `maxExtent`.
class ElSliverPersistentHeader extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final ElSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate delegate;
  ElSliverPersistentHeader({
    Key key,
    ElSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate delegate,
  })  : this.delegate = delegate,
        super(
            key: key,
            child:
                _ElSliverPersistentHeaderDelegateWrapper(delegate: delegate));

  @override
  _ElPersistentHeaderRenderSliver createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _ElPersistentHeaderRenderSliver(
        delegate.maxExtent, delegate.minExtent);
  }
}

class _ElSliverPersistentHeaderDelegateWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final ElSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate delegate;

  _ElSliverPersistentHeaderDelegateWrapper({Key key, this.delegate})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        final height = constraints.maxHeight;
        return delegate.build(context, delegate.maxExtent - height);
      });
}

class _ElPersistentHeaderRenderSliver extends RenderSliver
    with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox> {
  final double maxExtent;
  final double minExtent;

  _ElPersistentHeaderRenderSliver(this.maxExtent, this.minExtent);

  @override
  bool hitTestChildren(HitTestResult result,
      {@required double mainAxisPosition, @required double crossAxisPosition}) {
    if (child != null) {
      return child.hitTest(result,
          position: Offset(crossAxisPosition, mainAxisPosition));
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    /// The amount of scroll that extends the theoretical limit.
    /// I.e.: when the user drags down the list, although it already hit the
    /// top.
    ///
    /// This seems to be a bit of a hack, but I haven't found a way to get this
    /// information in another way.
    final overScroll =
        constraints.viewportMainAxisExtent - constraints.remainingPaintExtent;

    /// The actual Size of the widget is the [maxExtent] minus the amount the
    /// user scrolled, but capped at the [minExtent] (we don't want the widget
    /// to become smaller than that).
    /// Additionally, we add the [overScroll] here, since if there *is*
    /// "over scroll", we want the widget to grow in size and exceed
    /// [maxExtent].
    final actualSize =
        math.max(maxExtent - constraints.scrollOffset + overScroll, minExtent);

    /// Now layout the child with the [actualSize] as `maxExtent`.
    child.layout(constraints.asBoxConstraints(maxExtent: actualSize));

    /// We "clip" the `paintExtent` to the `maxExtent`, otherwise the list
    /// below stops moving when reaching the border.
    ///
    /// Tbh, I'm not entirely sure why that is.
    final paintExtent = math.min(actualSize, maxExtent);

    /// For the layout to work properly (i.e.: the following slivers to
    /// scroll behind this sliver), the `layoutExtent` must not be capped
    /// at [minExtent], otherwise the next sliver will "stop" scrolling when
    /// [minExtent] is reached,
    final layoutExtent = math.max(maxExtent - constraints.scrollOffset, 0.0);

    geometry = SliverGeometry(
      scrollExtent: maxExtent,
      paintExtent: paintExtent,
      layoutExtent: layoutExtent,
      maxPaintExtent: maxExtent,
    );
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      /// This sliver is always displayed at the top.
      context.paintChild(child, Offset(0.0, 0.0));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Now you can create your own `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` and override this param"

```dart
@override
  OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration get stretchConfiguration =>
      OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration();
```

By default if null, but once you added it will allow you to stretch the view.

This is the class I use:

```dart
class CustomSliverDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget child;
  final Widget title;
  final Widget background;
  final double topSafeArea;
  final double maxExtent;

  CustomSliverDelegate({
    this.title,
    this.child,
    this.maxExtent = 350,
    this.background,
    this.topSafeArea = 0,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset,
      bool overlapsContent) {
    final appBarSize = maxExtent - shrinkOffset;
    final proportion = 2 - (maxExtent / appBarSize);
    final percent = proportion < 0 || proportion > 1 ? 0.0 : proportion;
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData.dark(),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: maxExtent),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              top: 0,
              child: background,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Opacity(opacity: percent, child: child),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: AppBar(
                title: Opacity(opacity: 1 - percent, child: title),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration get stretchConfiguration =>
      OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration();

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight + topSafeArea;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: I found another way how to stretch an image in `AppBar`
here is minimal reproducible example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 200,
            title: Text('Title'),
            stretch: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/2pQ5qum.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: List.generate(50, (index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 72,
                  color: Colors.blue[200],
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text('Item $index'),
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The magic is in - `stretch: true` and `BouncingScrollPhysics()` properties.
There is not complicated listeners, stageful widgets so on. Just `FlexibleSpaceBar` with an image on `background`.

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't increase the size of the `SliverAppBar` when I scroll down. I tried modifying your code, so it also increases the size, but this obviously doesn't really work, because then it interferes with the rest of the scrolling items.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Just FYI I'm using a `SliverPersistentHeader` not a `SliverAppBar`, so I'm not sure this will work as well.

Comment: i just tried, it works with SliverPersistentHeader as well

Comment: Mh, but in your screen capture, I think that the same issue is visible: When you look at the list (Item 0, Item 1, etc...) being dragged down, the distance between the list and the header increases. Do you know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by simply creating a custom `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

Just override the getter for stretchConfiguration. Here's my code in case this is useful.

```
class LargeCustomHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  LargeCustomHeader(
      {this.children,
      this.title = '',
      this.childrenHeight = 0,
      this.backgroundImage,
      this.titleHeight = 44,
      this.titleMaxLines = 1,
      this.titleTextStyle = const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
          letterSpacing: 0.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          height: 1.2,
          color: ColorConfig.primaryContrastColor)}) {}

  final List<Widget> children;
  final String title;
  final double childrenHeight;

  final String backgroundImage;

  final int _fadeDuration = 250;
  final double titleHeight;
  final int titleMaxLines;

  final double _navBarHeight = 56;

  final TextStyle titleTextStyle;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(35.0)),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.loose,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (this.backgroundImage != null) ...[
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                  placeholder: "assets/images/image-placeholder.png",
                  image: backgroundImage,
                  placeholderScale: 1,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  imageScale: 0.1,
                  fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  fadeOutDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: _navBarHeight + titleHeight,
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: (shrinkOffset >= childrenHeight / 3) ? 0 : 1,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: _fadeDuration),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[if (children != null) ...children],
                    ))),
            Positioned(
              top: _navBarHeight,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              height: titleHeight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 30, bottom: 0, left: 30, top: 5),
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: (shrinkOffset >= childrenHeight + (titleHeight / 3))
                      ? 0
                      : 1,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: _fadeDuration),
                  child: Text(
                    title,
                    style: titleTextStyle,
                    maxLines: titleMaxLines,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              height: _navBarHeight,
              child: AppBar(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  title: AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity:
                        (shrinkOffset >= childrenHeight + (titleHeight / 3))
                            ? 1
                            : 0,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: _fadeDuration),
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                    ),
                  )),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => _navBarHeight + titleHeight + childrenHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _navBarHeight;

  // @override
  // FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration get snapConfiguration => FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration() ;

  @override
  OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration get stretchConfiguration =>
      OverScrollHeaderStretchConfiguration(
        stretchTriggerOffset: maxExtent,
        onStretchTrigger: () {},
      );

  double get maxShrinkOffset => maxExtent - minExtent;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    //TODO: implement specific rebuild checks
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I have a easy way to code.

By use `SliverAppBar` and inside child widget `leading`, `FlexibleSpaceBar` and inside child widget `title`.

And by `LayoutBuilder` we can make some animation.

[image: gif image]

[Full code link](https://gist.github.com/FantaZZ/0cc27e8030aa0e3a648e7a4aee35ffde)

```
SliverAppBar(
  toolbarHeight: _appBarHeight,
  collapsedHeight: _appBarHeight,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
  shadowColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
  expandedHeight: maxWidth,
  /// ========================================
  /// custom your app bar
  /// ========================================
  leading: Container(
    width: 100,
    height: _appBarHeight,
    // color: Colors.blueAccent,
    child: Center(
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.black),
    ),
  ),
  pinned: true,
  stretch: true,
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    stretchModes: [
      StretchMode.fadeTitle,
      StretchMode.blurBackground,
      StretchMode.zoomBackground,
    ],
    titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    title: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, __) {
        var height = __.maxHeight;
        /// ========================================
        /// custom animate you want by height change
        /// ========================================
        // Logger.debug(__.maxHeight);
        return Stack(
          children: [
            if (height > 100)
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
              ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
    background: Image.network(
      'https://xx',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `SliverAppBar` with `stretch:true` and pass the widget you want to display in the appbar as `flexibleSpace`.

Here is an example

```
CustomScrollView(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverAppBar(
      stretch: true,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      expandedHeight: 300,
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text("My Custom Bar"),
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        )
      ],
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
        stretchModes: 
        [
          StretchMode.zoomBackground,
          StretchMode.blurBackground
        ],
        background: YourCustomWidget(),
      ),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        [
          Container(color: Colors.red, height: 300.0),
          Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 300.0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```