# Flutter: image zoom animation when scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm would like to recreate the image zoom effect initiated when a user scrolls.

This is a screen capture of the app Apple music, it uses this effect/animation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVeGNFX-raQ

[image]

How is this created?
(or are there tutorials, because I didn't find any)

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: Hi Karel, are you able to find the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005307/how-to-get-the-sliverpersistentheader-to-overgrow/56007641#56007641 especially last answer with rating 1

Answer (score 0):

Now a days you can do easily by using SliverAppBar .
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSc7qFzxHDw